# Spring mvc, hibernate, crud

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, crud

difference between `<tx:annotation-driven>` and `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"`

Comment: Your field type should most probably be `BookService`, not `BookServiceImpl`.

Comment: thanks it works for me

Comment: if we change <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
to
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />, it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add servlet mapping tag

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

It was better for new problem posed a new question

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the interface `BookService` as field type in the controller.
Cause of this problem is that Spring prefers to use interfaces for AOP because it can use JDK proxies.

> Spring AOP uses either JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB to create the
>   proxy for a given target object. (JDK dynamic proxies are preferred
>   whenever you have a choice).
>
> If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface
>   then a JDK dynamic proxy will be used. All of the interfaces
>   implemented by the target type will be proxied. If the target object
>   does not implement any interfaces then a CGLIB proxy will be created.

For more information read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use the interface BookService as field type in the controller,the problem is solved.Then, I run the program and there is no error.However, there is no response to my url requests.How can i fix it?

[This is problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVx2l.jpg)

## web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>





<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>``
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: You should ask a second question, not use the answer-space to ask it